# hacer visibles elementos en html en proyecto de django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Vengo a solicitar su ayuda, en un proyecto Django de pagina web, tengo una barra lateral que muestra diversas opciones, necesito que al momento de hacer clic en

Tipo de persona

se hagan visibles dos botoneras, cree un script en JS para que cumpliera esa funcion , pero aun asi no se hacen visibles en la pagina, si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaria muy agradecido

```
<ul class="nav child_menu">
    {% if user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'direccion' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'admin' %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_sucursales' %}">Establecimientos</a></li>                          
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_tipos_persona' %}" id="tipo-persona-link">Tipo de persona</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_generos' %}">Genero persona</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_personas' %}">Persona</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_alumnos' %}">Alumno</a></li>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'convivencia escolar' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'direccion' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'inspectoria' or user.id_perfil.id_permiso.descripcion|lower == 'admin' %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'listar_cursos' %}">Curso</a></li>
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>

<div id="botoneras" style="display: none;">
    <!-- Contenido de las botoneras -->
    <button>Apoderado</button>
    <button>Docente</button>
</div>

<script>
    // Obtener el enlace de "Tipo de persona"
    const tipoPersonaLink = document.getElementById("tipo-persona-link");

    // Agregar un evento de clic al enlace de "Tipo de persona"
    tipoPersonaLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Evitar el comportamiento predeterminado de navegación

        // Mostrar u ocultar las botoneras
        const botoneras = document.getElementById("botoneras");
        if (botoneras.style.display === "none") {
            botoneras.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            botoneras.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
</script>
```